# CSS - absolute positioning and fluid divs

Tags: css, html, width, css-position

I need to make a layout that looks like this:

```
[250px - fixed div]  [fluid div, must expand depending on the width of the body and the 2 divs next/before it]  [250px - fixed div]
```

is this possible?
the container of all 3 divs is also fluid (100% width).
all these divs contain background images (left + right + repeating center image) and should stay in the back.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible, google around for "css 3 column layouts" or different keywords, there are lots of examples out there already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading [The Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/) for a complete tutorial walk-through and description of necessary browser hacks and such for creating the layout.

In addition, I would advise that you consider placing a max-width either on the containing element or your fluid div (for instance:`#container {max-width:1024px;}`), because on exceptionally high resolutions / large screens, a stretching div can become obnoxiously large to the point of user frustration.